# Why can't I view pages in the admin section of django-cms?

Tags: django, content-management-system

I install django-cms.
I try to use the example spplied by the installation package.

I have some questions :

I can add pages to my site. but when I try to list all my pages in the tree-view (using the "Select page to change" view) . The tree view is blank?
Does anyone had the same problem?

Comment: hi agbrand, could you mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

- Are you running the local web server?
- When you load the page that shows the tree view, are the static files being loaded?
- Can you see successful requests for .js and .css files?
- When you load the default site http://127.0.0.1:8080/ can you see the Django Logo?
- When you load the tree view, all you see is some text like "filtering off"?

My guess is that the static files aren't being served correctly.
This isn't hard to fix, just requires a little trouble shooting.

**Ensure your Static Files Are Setup correctly**

In your *settings.py*:

1. Ensure that you have set your own
   **MEDIA_URL** variable to something
   other than 'Media' as this conflicts
   with the default CMS Admin media Url. There's a note
   at the bottom of the documentation
   about this. 
   I created a folder in my
   project called **site_media** and
   then set **MEDIA_URL =
   '/site_media/'**
2. Have you copied the contents of **pythonpath\site-packages\django_cms\cms\media\** into your media directory?

In your urls.py have you setup the static routes? This isn't in the CMS documentation as its [part of the Django doco](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

The following is what I have:

```
urlpatterns += patterns
(r'^site_media/(?P.*)$',
  'django.views.static.serve',
 {'document_root': 'D:/myproject/site_media'}),
```

HTH - feel free to ask questions.